# How to detect if android phone has dual back camera

Tags: java, android, camera

How do I detect if android phone has dual back camera

I tried

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for(String id: manager.getCameraIdList())
            Log.e("dualtest", id);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it gives me only 2 ids 0 and 1.

Comment: what is your api level

Comment: api level is 24+

Comment: Why would you want to know that?

Comment: Get **Build.model** and try to match it against https://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?chkDualCamera=selected 

Comment: Have you tried [REQUEST_MAX_NUM_OUTPUT_RAW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#REQUEST_MAX_NUM_OUTPUT_RAW) ?

Answer (score 1):

Nishant, I tested the same on my Mi A1 and found that I get only two cameras. Were you able to find an answer?

```
for(String camera_id : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()){
    Log.d(TAG, "Available Cameras: id: " + camera_id + " and rear facing = " + (cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(camera_id).get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK));
}
```

Output:

> Available Cameras: id: 0 and rear facing = true
>
> Available Cameras: id: 1 and rear facing = false

Also found [this link](http://mobile.developer.lge.com/develop/dev-guides/lg-dual-camera-developer-guide/development#AccessingCameras) on LG dual camera access. It would be helpful if one can help on answering how to enable the second rear facing camera on Mi A1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Camera.getCameraInfo` Like follows. If you use api lvl 9

```
List<Integer> camID = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
        for(int i=0;i<Camera.getNumberOfCameras();i++){
            CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i,cameraInfo);
            if(cameraInfo.facing==CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                camID.add(i);
                break;
            }
        }
```

If you are using api lvl 21 you can use Camera2 api

```
List<String> camID = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    for(String cameraId:manager.getCameraIdList()){
        CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        Integer facing = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
        if(facing==CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
            camID.add(cameraId);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Reference

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getCameraInfo(int,%20android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo)

Comment: Camera.getNumberOfCameras returns 2 but i am using mi a1 which 3 cameras 1 front and dual back

Comment: I can confirm on MI A1 it is returning 2. And surprisingly, preview size isn't coming 4k. Max is 1080 :(

Answer (score 0):

Just a personal opinion here, but I don't think that this is possible (although I don't have any proof for this). Usually, the 2 dual cameras are very different on their own: aperture, zoom, colours and so on. They may not work so well on their own, but do a great job when the software combines the input from both. But if the processing software is very good, you don't even need the dual camera setup (take Google's camera app which does an excellent job at this). In conclusion, there is a big variety of how this dual cameras are made, and if a single camera work on some setups, on others it may be totally useless. This is why I believe that even though you have 2 cameras on the back, they are treated as a single camera by the system. Also, given the amount of Android phones manufacturers, there would be hard to align all of them in order to develop an unified API. Depending on the manufacturer, they may give you some APIs to access only one camera, but that will work only on their phones, and until Google doesn't switch to the dual camera setup, I don't believe that there will be an API that provides this feature.

Comment: @lulian the thing is i just need to give a feature if their is dual back camera on phone . so all i want is to know if dual back camera exists or not i searched a lot but i didn't get anything.

Comment: May I ask what feature?

Comment: one feature is to give bokeh effect if possible

Comment: Well, this is already made by the 2 cameras plus the software (or if you are Google, only by the software). You don't have to do anything else.

Comment: @lulian tell me one thin does both cameras captures 2 different pictures simultaneously and merge both later, or only 1 image is taken?

Comment: Not sure, but I believe that in a few words it works like this. The actual process is more complex

Comment: To produce the boceh effect, don't you need a way to independently access the two cameras? On the face of it, LG is the first to provide SDK for that,  see http://mobile.developer.lge.com/develop/sdks/lg-dual-camera/ (for V20, V10, G5)